# Check if an windows store app is started for the first time

Tags: windows-store-apps, registration

I am developing a windows store desktop app which needs one time registration. If the user has not registered, ie. when the app is starting for the first time, I want to display the registration page. And if the user has already registered, I want to display another page.How to do this?

Comment: use sqlitedb.check the user details already exist or not.redirect to registration page if not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the [LocalFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder.aspx) to store a flag file.

Every time the app starts looks there for a file, if it is not there show the user the registration page and create the file. If the file is already there you can be sure the user already registered himself (if you save the file after the user successfully registers).

**EDIT**: [LocalSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx) looks like a better place for something that small. You don't need it to be a file, it is just a setting.

Comment: thanks. it is a good way. similar to storing a variable in a file and changing it upon registration.

Comment: If that registration would be shared across the user's devices, then use RoamingSettings or the RoamingFolder instead. The Roaming contents are installed on other devices with installation of the app, so the flag (and other user information you might want) would be there on first run. What this won't quite solve is if the user uninstalls the app on all devices and the roaming data gets deleted (after something like 30 days), in which case you might start with a user that's registered in the past. Here, you might offer an "I'm already registered' option on startup just in case.

Comment: There are ways, also, to store settings that you can pick up even if the roaming data is deleted, if you have your own backing store (e.g. an Azure Mobile Services table). I just blogged about this on http://www.kraigbrockschmidt.com/2014/07/31/store-tidbits-1-persisting-data-after-uninstall-and-older-app-versions/, as the key is getting a unique per-user/per-application (but not device) ID, which you can obtain through the Store's AppReceipt.ID.